# In Hortensia Saga, is Alfred going to die in the end?

Tags: hortensia-saga

In *Hortensia Saga* anime, at the end of the opening, it seems like Alfred came close to Marius from behind but when she looks back at him, he was gone and she looked a little bit sad.

Is Alfred going to die in the end of the anime?

Answer (score 1):

In the manga,

> Alfred dies in Chapter 9.